# Fast way for multiple processes to read from central source in Python?

Tags: python, performance, queue, multiprocessing

I'm looking for a fast way for multiple processes (in multiprocessing.Pool()) to read from a central datasource.  Currently I have a file which is read into a queue (using multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()), then a worker pool is started and its processes read from this queue.  It works fine, but when I'm working with files which are multiple GBs in size, this becomes a problem as the managed queue is ~7 times slower than a regular python queue.

I think this is down to the way that the manager is in a separate process and it has to communicate over a socket rather than directly with the memory.

Here is the code I am using (the get_records function just reads bytestream for each record from the file and returns it)

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manager = Manager()
mgr_q = manager.Queue()
map(mgr_q.put, get_records(f))
```

So maybe there's a better way to handle this?

---

Here are some stats about the speed of reading one of my data files (~3GB) into various data types:

Reading into a regular python list.  Rate is 229.377 MB/sec

```
l = []
map(l.append, get_records(f))
```

Reading in to a regular queue.  Rate is 74.035 MB/sec

```
import Queue
q = Queue.Queue()
map(q.put, get_records(f))
```

Reading in to a multiprocessing.queues queue.  Rate is 67.718 MB/sec

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
mq = Queue()
map(mq.put, get_records(f))
```

Finally reading into a managed queue.  Rate is 9.568 MB/sec

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manager = Manager()
mgr_q = manager.Queue()
map(mgr_q.put, get_records(f))
```

Rates are calculated by `rate = duration / filesize / 1024 / 1024`

Comment: A `Queue` is not meant to transport a huge amount of data.  Try putting the actual data in shared memory, and only communicate pointers to the chunks the workers should work on via the `Queue`.

Comment: @Sven: Okay, I'll look into that. I just ran a test with just adding integers into a Queue and managed queue is still ten times slower than a regular queue ([code and results](http://pastebin.com/hNWr31vQ])).  Would using pointers to memory be any different here?

Comment: @Sven: I'll go ahead and implement this anyway, to see how it affects performance.

Comment: The point here is to somehow reduce the number of entries you add to the queue.  If you split your problem into too many chunks, your manager will become the bottleneck.  Try to do as much work as possible in the workers (for example splitting the data into records).

Comment: Makes lots of sense.  I'm looking at passing records into the queue in chunks of, say, 100 records at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just doing reads on the file it's safe to have multiple processes read at same time. Instead of passing data in the queue, just pass the offset and count. Than in the workers do:

```
f.seek(offset)
get_records(f, count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this makes no noticeable difference -- e.g reduces execution time from 35secs 34secs with a 65MB file being parsed.

Comment: Adding in chunking of the records (as suggested by Sven in the OP comments) has made a massive difference.  I'm experimenting with the size of the chunks to see which is most efficient.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah, what I actually meant by "count" is what you call "chunk size".